# How gradient effect in mockup is made using Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, gradient, background

I found this cool design in Dribbble and wonder how these layers of curves are made in Photoshop. Buildings in the background is also blended well. Is there any proper method to blend them into the background layer? Or is it just made by reducing the opacity level?
Would appreciate if there are links which explains what kind of design it is or guidelines to build them.

Thanks in Advance :)
 [image]

My try is here:[image]

Comment: Hi Hemalatha, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: @Vincent Hi thanks. and yes, i ll edit and post it again with how i tried. I have given shadows too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are most probably vector paths with manipulated transparency. You can create vector paths using Pen Tool (hotkey: P) then assign them proper fill (color or gradient) and then manipulate their transparency in the layers panel.

EDIT:

1. Create a vector path using Pen Tool (hotkey: P). Then right-click inside the path and choose "convert to selection".

[image: 1]

2. Choose Marquee Tool (hotkey: M). Right-click and choose: select inverted.

[image: 2]

3. Now, while still having your Marquee Tool selected right-click and select: Layer by Copy.

[image: 3]

4. Now that you have your new layer (in the shape of a wave) go to layers panel and click it's Thumbnail holding Ctrl button.

[image: 4]

5. Now while you have your new wave-shaped layer assing a fill to it by pressing Shift + F5 and choose the color of your liking.

[image: 5]

6. Now, manipulate the transparency of your layer in the transparency panel using the sliders and the blending mode.

[image: 6]

7. Create as many waves you wish and try different approaches of blending, gradients, fills, transparency and so on till you get the outcome you love.

Hope that helps!

Comment: should i give any shadow? Gradient didnt work, but fill color is more appropriate

Comment: I'll make a lil tutorial for you. Wait a second.

Comment: this is cool..! so no need to create shadow effects and stuffs right?

Comment: Yup, I still wish to remind you that this is merely one of very many ways to achieve this effect. However, I find this one to be the most flexible and thus I suggested it.